# SSH with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh

Attempting to create files and such on new vps that was created using api. This function does not run the second ssh command for some reason. Before this function is run there's another that is also run that sends a few commands to install packages before it installs the files. I have the function running after a timer has run out so that it can use some of the packages to run the commands like screen. It runs the first ssh but not the second one and i have tried with a timer up to 180 seconds.

```
function CreateServer( SIP, GUSER, SPORT ) {
var CDir = "";
var RPassword = generator.generate({
    length: 10,
    numbers: true
});
var ssh = new SSH({
    host: SIP,
    user: 'root',
    key: fs.readFileSync('serverkey.ppk')
    //pass: 'password'
});

ssh.exec('if test -d /home/' + GUSER + '; then echo "exist"; fi', {
    out: function(stdout) {
        CDir = stdout;
        //console.log(stdout);
    }
}).start();
setTimeout(function(){
    if(CDir == DMkdir) {
        console.log("User on machine not adding......");
        ssh.exec('chown -R ' + GUSER + ':' + GUSER + ' /home/' + GUSER + '; su - ' + GUSER + ' -c "cd /home/' + GUSER + '/steamcmd ; screen -mdSL ' + SIP + ':' + SPORT + ' ./steamcmd.sh +login anonymous +force_install_dir /home/' + GUSER + '/' + SIP + '.' + SPORT + ' +app_update 4020 validate +quit"', {
            out: function(stdout) {
                //console.log(stdout);
            }
        }).start();             
    } else {
        console.log("User not on machine adding......");
        ssh.exec('cd /home/; sudo adduser ' + GUSER + ' --gecos "First Last,RoomNumber,WorkPhone,HomePhone" --disabled-password; echo "' + GUSER + ':' + RPassword + '" | sudo chpasswd; cd /home/' + GUSER + '/; mkdir steamcmd; cd /home/' + GUSER + '/steamcmd; wget https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steamcmd_linux.tar.gz; tar -xvzf steamcmd_linux.tar.gz; chown -R ' + GUSER + ':' + GUSER + ' /home/' + GUSER + '; su - ' + GUSER + ' -c "cd /home/' + GUSER + '/steamcmd ; screen -mdSL ' + SIP + ':' + SPORT + ' ./steamcmd.sh +login anonymous +force_install_dir /home/' + GUSER + '/' + SIP + '.' + SPORT + ' +app_update 4020 validate +quit"', {
            out: function(stdout) {
                console.log(stdout);
            }
        }).start();
    }
}, 5 * 1000);
return true;
```

}

Comment: It's possible it's writing to stderr and you're not accounting for that, but it could also be that your information hasn't come back yet. If it's the latter I have an answer that will likely work for you that I'm writing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming everything is correct besides your problem with handling two asynchronous events. Given that I can't see where `DMkdir` is coming from and just of context of your other code I am assuming that just like `CDir` its value is being set asynchronously.

Assuming your using a recent version of node that uses native promises like Node version 6 and up then the following code will work for you. If your not using a more recent version of node you can use a promise library like [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) or [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) which will involve different syntax but it will be solved a similar way.

```
function sshPromise (string) {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ssh.exec(string, {
          // on correct output the promise needs to be 
          // resolved by calling the resolve function with the data
          out: resolve
          // not sure what the error property is but it needs 
          // to reject the promise with the error data
          onError: reject
      }).start();
    });
}

var CDirPromise = sshPromise('if test -d /home/' + GUSER + '; then echo "exist"; fi');

var DMkdirPromise = sshPromise('whatever command you did for this one obviously not this string');

Promise.all([CDirPromise, DMkdirPromise]).then(function ([CDir, DMKdir]) {
    // this then method will fire when all the promises resolve.
    if(CDir == DMkdir) {
        console.log("User on machine not adding......");
        ssh.exec('chown -R ' + GUSER + ':' + GUSER + ' /home/' + GUSER + '; su - ' + GUSER + ' -c "cd /home/' + GUSER + '/steamcmd ; screen -mdSL ' + SIP + ':' + SPORT + ' ./steamcmd.sh +login anonymous +force_install_dir /home/' + GUSER + '/' + SIP + '.' + SPORT + ' +app_update 4020 validate +quit"', {
            out: function(stdout) {
                //console.log(stdout);
            }
        }).start();             
    } else {
        console.log("User not on machine adding......");
        ssh.exec('cd /home/; sudo adduser ' + GUSER + ' --gecos "First Last,RoomNumber,WorkPhone,HomePhone" --disabled-password; echo "' + GUSER + ':' + RPassword + '" | sudo chpasswd; cd /home/' + GUSER + '/; mkdir steamcmd; cd /home/' + GUSER + '/steamcmd; wget https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steamcmd_linux.tar.gz; tar -xvzf steamcmd_linux.tar.gz; chown -R ' + GUSER + ':' + GUSER + ' /home/' + GUSER + '; su - ' + GUSER + ' -c "cd /home/' + GUSER + '/steamcmd ; screen -mdSL ' + SIP + ':' + SPORT + ' ./steamcmd.sh +login anonymous +force_install_dir /home/' + GUSER + '/' + SIP + '.' + SPORT + ' +app_update 4020 validate +quit"', {
            out: function(stdout) {
                console.log(stdout);
            }
        }).start();
    }
}).catch(function (err) {
    // handle the error one of the promises rejected.
});
```

You should do handling of errors as well (when saying `ssh.exec` there should be a way to handle the error output I just guessed it was `onError` but you should change it to what it actually is. I don't know what ssh library you are using so I just guessed it was `onError`.) as it seems currently that your code is not checking for errors being thrown.

I'll write just a bit about promises. They are very good for asynchronous events that happen once. They are also good at handling errors with these asynchronous events. A promise has three states: 'pending' which is an unfinished state, 'resolved' which is a successful finished state, or rejected which is an unsuccessful finished state likely caused by an error. You can handle resolved values in a promise with a `.then` method and handle rejected values with the `.catch` method.

I suggest reading the below links about Promises to truly get a grasp on them.

- [MDN: "Using promises"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)
- [MDN: "Promise.all"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)
- [Google Developers: "JavaScript Promises: an Introduction"](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises)

Good luck. :)

### EDIT:

Well according to the comments the problem is quite a bit simpler. All you really need to do is the following which is to just put your function to run after CDir is available on the out property of ssh.exec.

```
ssh.exec('if test -d /home/' + GUSER + '; then echo "exist"; fi', {
    out: function (CDir) {
        if(CDir == DMkdir) {
            console.log("User on machine not adding......");
            ssh.exec('chown -R ' + GUSER + ':' + GUSER + ' /home/' + GUSER + '; su - ' + GUSER + ' -c "cd /home/' + GUSER + '/steamcmd ; screen -mdSL ' + SIP + ':' + SPORT + ' ./steamcmd.sh +login anonymous +force_install_dir /home/' + GUSER + '/' + SIP + '.' + SPORT + ' +app_update 4020 validate +quit"', {
                out: function(stdout) {
                    //console.log(stdout);
                }
            }).start();             
        } else {
            console.log("User not on machine adding......");
            ssh.exec('cd /home/; sudo adduser ' + GUSER + ' --gecos "First Last,RoomNumber,WorkPhone,HomePhone" --disabled-password; echo "' + GUSER + ':' + RPassword + '" | sudo chpasswd; cd /home/' + GUSER + '/; mkdir steamcmd; cd /home/' + GUSER + '/steamcmd; wget https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steamcmd_linux.tar.gz; tar -xvzf steamcmd_linux.tar.gz; chown -R ' + GUSER + ':' + GUSER + ' /home/' + GUSER + '; su - ' + GUSER + ' -c "cd /home/' + GUSER + '/steamcmd ; screen -mdSL ' + SIP + ':' + SPORT + ' ./steamcmd.sh +login anonymous +force_install_dir /home/' + GUSER + '/' + SIP + '.' + SPORT + ' +app_update 4020 validate +quit"', {
                out: function(stdout) {
                    console.log(stdout);
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: DMkdir is just a string would just removing the promise for that one in the promise all change anything?

Comment: @RaulGonzales no actually if DMkdir is not a value that is set over time it is a much simpler solution. So it is just a string but do you set it directly without it being set at a different time?

Comment: It is set directly from the start of the app

Comment: Okay I'll update my answer accordingly. @RaulGonzales

Comment: @RaulGonzales I've updated my answer. I think that should work for you.

Comment: I tried that before but it did not work for some reason I will try it again once I get home with the code you just wrote.

Comment: Did not work even when i used err instead of out to check for errors. No output just looks like its not being run and i checked the vps as well.

Comment: @RaulGonzales Well there's probably a different property on that object your sending into the ssh.exec that handles errors. It's possible it's erroring or something related to that do you know what package you are getting the ssh thing from? If you do you could go read its docs.

Comment: It's simple ssh module. Also i did read the docs and how to display error output. just doesn't work q.q

Comment: Maybe your bash script is running nothing it appears it will only echo to stdout if it exists. I'm no expert in bash though. You could try running the bash script with the complete string it has when it hits that line and see if it outputs anything.

Comment: @RaulGonzales sorry I forgot to tag you in the last comment.

Comment: Forgot i could just make a bash script and just run that instead of making multiple connections :V. Thanks for the idea xD! And yeah it is supposed to output data. I have tried it without it being inside any other ssh command and it works.

Comment: Got everything working now! Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @RaulGonzales hey glad I could help.